# Stability criterion for leapfrog in relativistic physics

Tags: simulations, graphene, molecular-dynamics

I am doing a 2D MD simulations of charge carriers in graphene using the [Leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) algorithm. I am trying to prove that, in some specific cases (when distance between particles is small), the method is unstable.

The Hamiltonian is given as $H =  |\vec{p_{1}}| + |\vec{p_2}| - \frac{\alpha}{r_{12}}$. With $p$ the momentums, $\alpha$ some numerical constant and $r_{12}$ some constants.

The leapfrog iteration would be:

$$
\vec{p_i} \to \vec{p_i} - 0.5 \Delta t \frac{\alpha}{r_{ij}^2} \hat{r_{ij}}\\
\vec{x_i} \to \vec{x_i} + \Delta t \hat{p_i} \\
\vec{p_i} \to \vec{p_i} - 0.5 \Delta t \frac{\alpha}{r_{ij}^2} \hat{r_{ij}}
$$

where the vectors with hat's are the direction vectors. 
I expect the stability to break down when $r_{ij}$ gets small. Yet, I tried using analysis from [this (page 7 onward)](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/leapfrog.pdf) source and it didn't really help.

Also, a different way to derive leapfrog is to define coordinate shift operators $L_p$ and $L_r$ that move $p \to p +\Delta p$ and $x \to x + \Delta x$. Then the differential equation can be written as:
$$
f(p(t), r(t)) = \exp\left(t (L_p + L_r) \right) f(p(0), r(0)).
$$
Using Trotter's identity we can write:
$$
\exp\left( \Delta t (A + B) \right) \approx \exp\left( 0.5\Delta t A \right) \exp\left( \Delta t B \right) \exp\left(0.5 \Delta t A \right)
$$
and this is exactly the Leapfrog algorithm. I tried figuring out if things breakdown in 1D case of two particles going straight at each other. To do this I worked out the commutator term $[L_p,L_r]$ that comes up in [Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) formula. This also didn't help.

Anyone has a fresh look or has some derivations that go beyond basic 1D cases where things go nicely? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For completness sake: I have an ongoing bounty for this exact question on the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3073355/) exchange. I don't expect much contributions there - it has been ignored by the community there so far.